# Python: why do functions in math module accept Decimal objects as arguments?

Tags: python, math, decimal

Bizzarely, every function from Python's math module seems to work just fine with Decimal objects. For example: frexp, exp, cos.

When I type `print(math.frexp(decimal.Decimal('2341.12412')))`, Python prints the correct answer, which is `(0.57156... , 12)`, and doesn't throw any exceptions.

I would assume that the math module would be written in low-level C, relying as heavily as possible on hardware math operations for efficiency. So... why would it work for Decimal objects?

Did they put a type check into the math functions, and switch to a different implementation if the argument is a Decimal? I didn't see anything like that mentioned in the docs. It could also be that the Decimal is automatically being converted to a float, but that doesn't make any sense, either.

Yeah, I'm confused.

Comment: Presuambly, they're being converted to floats.

Comment: Extend the functions of the `Decimal` object and see what is being called on it when you pass it in.

Comment: I just tried that now. I extended the Decimal class and overrode the \_\_add__ and \_\_multiply__ functions to print a message and call the equivalent Decimal function. So far, it seems like none of the math functions are calling \_\_add__ or \_\_multiply__, because the messages don't print when I call them(exp, frexp, etc). Probably the Decimal is being converted to a float...

Comment: Notice that the returned result is not a `Decimal`, that is a clue.

Comment: @Ryan yes, my guess would be you have to override `__float__` to see the evidence. If `exp` etc. were implemented in terms of Python's `__add__` and `__multiply__` it would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: Try extending the Decimal class and overwrite `__float__`. The math functions expect a float, and if one isn't provided, but the type implements `__float__`, it will call `__float__` to convert it into a float. The same holds true for functions that expect an int/long. They will try to call `__int__` to convert a non-int type into an int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well looking at the `math module.c` I got this:

```
static PyObject *
math_frexp(PyObject *self, PyObject *arg)
{
    int i;
    double x = PyFloat_AsDouble(arg);
    if (x == -1.0 && PyErr_Occurred())
        return NULL;
    /* deal with special cases directly, to sidestep platform
       differences */
    if (Py_IS_NAN(x) || Py_IS_INFINITY(x) || !x) {
        i = 0;
    }
    else {
        PyFPE_START_PROTECT("in math_frexp", return 0);
        x = frexp(x, &i);
        PyFPE_END_PROTECT(x);
    }
    return Py_BuildValue("(di)", x, i);
}
```

Looking at the code, it does in fact use `float` (`PyFloat_AsDouble`)

Again same thing for `exp`,

```
static PyObject *
math_factorial(PyObject *self, PyObject *arg)
{
    long x;
    PyObject *result, *odd_part, *two_valuation;

    if (PyFloat_Check(arg)) {
        PyObject *lx;
        double dx = PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE((PyFloatObject *)arg);
        if (!(Py_IS_FINITE(dx) && dx == floor(dx))) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
                            "factorial() only accepts integral values");
            return NULL;
        }
        lx = PyLong_FromDouble(dx);
        if (lx == NULL)
            return NULL;
        x = PyLong_AsLong(lx);
        Py_DECREF(lx);
.........................................................
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm honestly surprised they would convert the argument to a float. I would have thought it would be better to let the programmer make the conversion himself... but what do I know?